# How can I communicate between two different Salesforce LWC which are in two different window

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

I have one LWC having one button on click of that button i want to open one separate browser window having one different LWC and then I want to pass data from second window to main browser window.
I have open the second window using window.open() function but not able to pass the data.
Could you please suggest the solution for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [Lightning Message](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation) to communicate across windows/tabs. Please read the documentation for full details, it's a little complicated, but basically the recipient needs to `subscribe` when it is loaded, and `unsubscribe` when it is unloaded, and the sender needs to simply `publish` a message when it wants to send a message. You need to create a [Lightning Message Channel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_lightningmessagechannel.htm) in order for this to work.

Comment: Yaa Someday before  I got blockers on handling the publish Message. As @sfdcfox said Here the tricky part is the recipient needs to subscribe when it is loaded.

Comment: @sfdcfox and vignesh, How to handle subscribe when it is loaded,could you please explain or give some sample code, I have tried but not able to pass data to main window.Thanks!

Comment: @sfdcfox: Is there a way to send LMS Message from LWC to a AURA Action Button ?